# C++ / GCC - Why does this compile

Tags: c++, gcc

Coding away this evening (I realise it's Valentine's Day) and came across something strange...

I have the following line:

```
std:;cout << freqs[summations[i]] / 1000 * 10 << std::endl;
```

This compiles. However, if I do this, it will not compile.

```
std;;cout << freqs[summations[i]] / 1000 * 10 << std::endl;
```

I don't have any strict properties on in my compile line. However, I wouldn't have thought GCC would allow this to be compiled and output. Why is this?

Comment: goto's in most firms are forbidden so people haven't seen single label in entire career.

Comment: @PiotrNycz How do you mean `goto` have I used such a statement..?

Comment: Most people have seen a `default:` label, I expect, inside a `switch`, of course.

Comment: @Cornstalks damn you ;) thank you!! This can be closed!

Comment: @user1326876: I knew I had seen this before, but it took forever for me to find the original question, so I certainly don't blame you for asking it again (since it was so dang hard to find)!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `default:` is not a real label in a sense that ypu can't `goto default;`

Comment: @PiotrNycz: true enough; you can't goto a case label, either.  ISO/IEC 14882:2012 Section 6.1 **Labels** states _Case labels and `default` labels shall occur only in switch statements._ and 6.6.4 **The `goto` statement** says _The goto statement unconditionally transfers control to the statement labeled by the identifier._ and, of course, `default` is a keyword, not an identifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line provides a label `std:` followed by a null statement -- the semicolon.

The rest uses `cout << ...` and means you must have a `using namespace std;` or `using  std::cout;` or something similar in effect.

The second uses an identifier `std` that isn't defined.

Comment: I think I understand where you're coming from. However, I do not not have `using namespace std;` or `using namespace std::cout` anywhere in my code

Comment: Well, something is there that allows `std::cout` without the prefix `std::` because you said it compiles.  The obvious thing to do is remove the `std::` from `std::endl` on the same line and see whether that compiles.  It's not 100% definitive if it does not because there could be a `using` declaration hidden somewhere.

Comment: Not hidden ;-) I've always been told not to include `using namespace std;` if using just `std::cout` mhm. This would therefore break the rules?

Comment: Did you try removing `std::` from `std::endl`?  I've compiled `void p(int i) { cout << i << std::endl; }` with `#include <iostream>` and it fails; add either `using namespace std;` or `using std::cout;` and it does compile.  You may have to preprocess the file (`g++ -E`) to find the `using` declaration or `using` directive.  Because of the compilation options I use, I had to add a `goto std;` to get the code to compile with the `std:;cout ...` notation.

Comment: And, just for the record, this was GCC 4.8.2 on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative and the command line options were: `g++ -g -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c x.cpp`.

Answer (score 6):

`std:;` is getting parsed as a label followed by an empty statement.

Answer (score 0):

`std:;` is a label. The other part is using [argument dependent name lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) to resolve the namespace.

Since you said you didn't use using namespace in your code. My guess is that it works because you are using std::endl in the end (if you removed std from the endl it won't compile). which is using [argument dependent name lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). Which is part of the standard:

> ADL occurs only if the normal lookup of an unqualified name fails to
>   find a matching class member function. In this case, other namespaces
>   not considered during normal lookup may be searched where the set of
>   namespaces to be searched depends on the types of the function
>   arguments. Specifically, the set of declarations discovered during the
>   ADL lookup process, and considered for resolution of the function
>   name, is the union of the declarations found by normal lookup with the
>   declarations found by looking in the set of namespaces associated with
>   the types of the function arguments.

Comment: Sounds plausible, but doesn't seem to work.  Trying `void p(int i) { cout << i << std::endl; }` with just `#include <iostream>` and I get an error which I wouldn't if your hypothesis was accurate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, I agree, actually on MSVC2012 it didn't even compile the OP version. On g++ it did but only when I used a label. Which is puzzling me to be honest.

Comment: I guess we have to start asking 'which version of `g++` and which compilation options?'  I used `g++` 4.8.2 on an Ubuntu 12.04 derivative with options `g++ -g -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c x.cpp`.  I'm guessing you're using `g++` on Windows, so probably MinGW or Cygwin?